# Unit Test ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing

I need a tool or framework that will allow me to perform unit testing on ASP.Net applications.....Do you have one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean things like [nUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) (for code) and [**Selenium RC**](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) (for web application *integration* tests)

Comment: I forgot to mention htat it has to be a whitebox test....Does nUnit have support for that?

Comment: I think you are talking about Integration Testing then as white box testing is dependant upon implementation.

Therefore, Selenium is your answer as it allows you to write tests for each 'user path' through your web application.

Comment: We need to perform a test on the backend codes(C# codes) only and on a functional level. So testing would be per function. We tried PEX but i consider pex as a blackbox test because it only provides random inputs and then process for the output. The problem is we need to check some stuffs within the function like the insertion in DB and verification of some method variables if it had the expected values.

Comment: Ok, well you can use aspects of nUnit to write tests, however I think we are stretching the term 'unit testing' if real DB inserts are being performed. 

I would look in to Mocking. Moq (http://code.google.com/p/moq/) is an example of an ideal mocking framework. So you would test a class and mock out all it's dependencies - ensuring that you are testing just THAT class in a repeatable environment.

Comment: Ok thanks. BUt there's a sudden change. I am now required to insert testing scripts into the sourcecode itself and use the #define, #if, etc. to determine whether it is in testing mode. the problem here is asp.net don't build into class libraries or doesn't produce dll of the whole website project which i will  feed into NUnit

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the combination of [nUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php) and [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I think it is the best combination for ASP.net

Answer (score 1):

For unit, as well as integration, tests, take a look at [Ivonna](http://ivonna.biz/). Unlike Selenium, it doesn't test your client code, only server-side. It runs in-process and doesn't require a Web server. So, you can run your tests in debug mode, check variables etc.